# NSMutableArray removeAllObjects causing crash

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have a couple of arrays that I am trying to clear all objects from, but using removeAllObjects crashes the app and returns sigabrt. During my research I've found that although I am creating NSMutableArrays I could be creating an instance of a NSArray, but I am not sure if I am doing this or not... Here is everything I do to the arrays

```
ballArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ballVelocityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[ballArray addObject:MyUIImageView];

[ballVelocityArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myCGPoint]];

[ballVelocityArray replaceObjectAtIndex:SomeIndex withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:NewVelocity]];

[ballArray removeAllObjects];

[ballVelocityArray removeAllObjects];
```

That is everything I have done and I can't figure out why it keeps crashing... if there is only one object in the arrays it works fine, otherwise it crashes

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which of the two arrays causes a crash?

Comment: Which array is it crashing on? It looks like there is no relationship between the two arrays, so the code for the array that isn't crashing could be removed.

Comment: I believe both, I will try again, but i believe I commented one at a time out and it crashed both times

Comment: You should also go over your variable naming - MyUIImageView and SomeIndex look like class names, and you mix it with the right naming myCGPoint ... but that's of course not causing a crash.

Comment: what does it say when it crashes? Something like referencing a released object or so?

Comment: errr ... what is SomeIndex by the way? You just initialized the array, and it contains one value, so you cannot replace anything at SomeIndex, just at 0 ...

Comment: Ya, the UIImageView I am adding is actually called ball and the cgpoint ball velocity, just through that in to show what is in the array.  but it is both causing the crash and it says, 'program received signal sigabrt'

Comment: also  "  argc int 1
argv char ** 0x2fdffb90
*argv char * 0x2fdffc50
**argv char 47 '/'   "  and a whole bunch more that I don't understand

Comment: some index is the image views' tag. the ball array is to keep track of each ball that is moving and ballVelocityArray holds all the cgpoints that i use to move each ball independantly

Comment: i take it you are doing some more things to the objects you use in the arrays - it would help to post the complete code between the creation and the removeAllObjects

Comment: there's a bit of code there, but I did find a solution, not exactly what I was looking for, but it works. rather than removing all the objects, ballArray = nil; ballVelocityArray = nil; then reallocate the array when I need it again. It works exactly how I wanted it too, but not sure if there will be memory issues

Comment: you should release the arrays before setting them to nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because you are not managing memory correctly on one of the objects the array contains. When you remove an object from an array its retain count is decremented once.

You can put a break point on the line where you clear the array and use the debugger to see which object in there is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
ballArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ballVelocityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

After allocating object you are also releasing the object in dealloc function or somewhere else check this.If you are doing so then I would like to inform you that

```
[ballArray removeAllObjects];

[ballVelocityArray removeAllObjects];
```

removeAllObjects is not only removing all objects of array but also release the array object from memory so if again you are releasing the array object the memory pointer will reach on -1 and the application will crash.

So, make sure that You have not to release array object it you are already using

```
[ballArray removeAllObjects];

[ballVelocityArray removeAllObjects];
```

functions.